# Date Fields At Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highstock with multiple series. While plotting, the dates at the top are getting selected as below,
Start date : First series first date value
End Date : Last series last date value
But when i try to change the end date, by default it is getting adjusted as first series first value and last value as start and end date.

I tried setting the extremes but it didnt worked

Comment: Can you please provide the chart config with sample data or reproduce your issue in the working demo? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2aL6tpev/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.